# Security rules only allows to update a specific nested field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore database where I want a user only to be able to update a part of a document.
The documents looks like this:

```js
workplace: "Southern Warehouse 22",
area: "250m2",
employeeInfo: {
  count: 55,
  employeeStatus: {
    "hhjj-44-22-": "Working",
    "ytnf-59-90-": "Working",
    "oplk-34-16-": "Sick",
    ....
  }
  ...
}
...
```

The employees prop (hhjj-44-22-) is their auth uid. The user should Only be able to update their own employee info.
I've tried with this rule:

```js
allow update: if request.auth != null
  && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data)
        .affectedKeys().hasOnly(['employeeInfo.employees.' + request.auth.uid]);
```

but it wont work.. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: "it won't work" is really hard to help with. Security rules only become active once you execute code against them. Can you edit your question to include the [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that any of us can execute against your security rules that will reproduce the problem? Make sure that the code *proves* that it meets the conditions of your rules, i.e. have the code check that there is a current user, and that the key you are passing  in `employeeInfo.employees.$uid` is indeed the UID of the current user.

Comment: Fair point. I'm finding rules hard to debug. I'm updating the data using Firestores UpdateField(?). But I have no idea what the request.resource.data actually looks like :/

Answer (score 0):

First you may want to consider having the employee data in a sub-collection. This males rules simpler, will let you retrieve the info of one or only a few employees instead of all of them each time, and you wont have the risk of hitting the limit of 1Mo per doc.

That said, with your data structure you can use the following:

```
allow update: if request.auth != null
  && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['employeeInfo']);
  && request.resource.data.employeeInfo.diff(resource.data.get('employeeInfo', {})).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['employeeStatus'])
  && request.resource.data.employeeInfo.employeeStatus.diff(resource.data.get(['employeeInfo', 'employeeStatus'], {})).affectedKeys().hasOnly([request.auth.uid]);
```

Comment: I'm new to nosql. If a create a sub collection, will I have to select data by doing joins? Or are subcollections directly connected to the main collection? In that case a subcollections sounds like the way to go

Comment: You cant do joins in the general SQL-sense in Firestore. But yes, subcollections are directly connected to the main collection, so simple joins are fine.